# REST API backed by H2 DB behaves differently to IBM DB2 for inserting rows with XML strings

Tags: xml, rest, header, db2, h2

I'm a bit befuddled : I've got some table with one CLOB column that is supposed to contain an XML String. In my test suites I use an in-memory database, H2. In production I use IBM DB2. My test kept failing at some point, and I noticed that the reason is that when I add a row to my table in my test suites, the XML String contains a header (`<?xml ...>`). In my production database there is no such header.

The calls I do in production and in my test suite are identical : I make a REST call to insert some row with the same JSON input (mapped to a DTO that gets converted to XML with JAXB).

From some cursory reading online I have not been able to figure out what the cause of this is. Does IBM DB2 do something with XML Strings in the background, something I must have missed?

Comment: Do you use XML type when working with DB2 ? This type is not stored as string but as a binary stream. You can get back something equivalent to what you inserted with for example `select xmlserialize(content xmlcolumn as clob(50k) INCLUDING XMLDECLARATION) from yourtable`

Comment: No I don't, it's a regular CLOB. I'm a bit confused tbh.

Comment: Sorry but ... sure your strings contain what you expect at insert time when in production ?

Comment: I mean there is no way DB2 changes the value clob without been asked, whatever the value, there no XML feature I that's not linked to the XML type.

Comment: I haven't had the time to look into it yet (I found some way to get around it), but to give you an idea : I make my API request, it constructs a JSON programmatically, turns it into a string, sends it to my API with a POST call. I used breakpoints to look at the respective entity before/after insertion in the database. It always has the XML header in one of its fields (the one corresponding to the CLOB column). Then after program execution finishes I extract the CLOB out of the database (with DB Visualizer) ; no header.

Comment: I could try to make a minimal example (it might help me find what the problem is) but it's not trivial to do so of course.

Comment: Using different database platforms in test and production is A Bad Idea™.

Comment: How so? In any case, I tested it again. This is my flow : REST API -> Service -> DAO. First I call my API to insert an entity. With some breakpoints in the service in my 'addEntity' method (annotated with @Transactional) I noticed that before and after insertion (through the DAO) the XML header is in my entity's CLOB column. In a subsequent call to my API I fetch (instead of insert) the same entity. I put a breakpoint in my service, right after it finishes fetching the entity through the DAO. There is no XML header in the CLOB column. This suggests something happens at the DB level.

Comment: I noticed that my DB2 table's CLOB column is of type 'XML' (my apologies for the confusion). I didn't make that DB so I'm not very well acquainted with how DB2 works internally, and I couldn't find something in the docs yet but it looks like it does do something behind the scenes that I'm not aware of.